# SQL Server datediff and decimal rounding to even number

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-server-2012

I am using `datediff` to get the sum of the difference between 2 or more sets of dates, `aDateStart` and `aDateEnd`. The result should be 7.75, but the problem is it is rounding to 7.00 and storing that in the `Decimal(9,2)` database column, after the divide by 60 part. If I take away the "/60" from the SQL query, the result is 465.00, which is correct in minutes, but I would like the database to store 7.75

I'm getting the correct amount of seconds, but when I divide by 60, it rounds it to 7.00.

Data:

```
orderId    AdminId       aStartDate                 aEndDate
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
1          1        2021-04-02 08:00:00.000     2021-04-02 11:30:00.000
1          1        2021-04-02 08:00:00.000     2021-04-02 12:15:00.000
```

Relevant part of the stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_updateManagerStatus]
    @AdminId int,
    @OrderId int,
    @Id int,
    @Count1 decimal(9,2) OUTPUT

    SELECT 
        @Count1 = SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, aStartDate, aEndDate) / 60) 
    FROM
        Assignment  
    WHERE
        OrderId = @OrderId AND AdminId = @AdminId
BEGIN
    UPDATE JobSite 
    SET SiteActualTime = @Count1 
    WHERE Id = @Id AND AdminId = @AdminId
END
```

Relevant part of vb.net code:

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@AdminId", Variable.ToString()))                    
cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@OrderID", Request.QueryString("OrderNo")))
cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Id", JobSiteIdlbl.Text))
 Dim parameter As SqlParameter = New SqlParameter("@Count1", SqlDbType.Decimal)
      parameter.IsNullable = True
      parameter.Precision = 9
      parameter.Scale = 2
      parameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
      cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter)
con.Open()
rowsaffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: I can't help but wonder why you thought to also tag VB.NET code as C#? And is your issue in retrieving the result in VB.NET or the SQL query itself?

Comment: More people do C# than do VB, and the code is basically the same so C# people can help just as easily as VB. I do not know if the problem is in the VB code, or the SQL code, but the the value that gets stored in the database is the problem here.

Comment: The primary use of tags is to give us information about your question. You shouldn't add unrelated tags to "get more eyes" on your question. It wasn't egregious in your case, so I didn't downvote, but more extreme cases earn an instant downvote from me and - I think - from others.

Comment: point taken, thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are presumably performing an integer division there. You likely need to convert at least one - possibly both - of the values to type `decimal` in order to get a `decimal` result.

```sql
CONVERT(decimal(9,2), DATEDIFF(MINUTE, aStartDate, aEndDate)) / CONVERT(decimal(9,2), 60)
```

Comment: That did it. I resisted using the extra code (convert) because that I think it should work without converting, but of course I was wrong about that. Thank you!

Comment: just divide by `60.0`, if you do not want to do the extra `convert()`